# canopy ipython notebook blank

Tags: enthought, jupyter-notebook, canopy

I just installed canopy 1.0.0.1160 under OS 10.8.3
I can run ipython fine from the shell

```
Python 2.7.3 | 64-bit | (default, Mar 25 2013, 15:52:02) 
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 1.0.dev -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
```

However, when I run try to start an ipython notebook

```
ipython notebook --pylab=inline
```

it sometimes works in safari, not in chrome. And I can't run my old ipython notebooks created under EPD 7.3

Can I suspect that this is an ipython bug (I only found a [youtube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ztnp2Hu7y2w) with somebody having very similar issues? Are there any workarounds? Or should I wait for a new ipython build/canopy release?

Comment: Are you able to create a new notebook from within Canopy? (File / New / IPython Notebook)

Comment: @Jonathan in the meantime I downgraded to v13.1. It seems like this works well both from terminal and from within canopy. Thanks. +1 for the ability to downgrade easily and the option for opening a python notebook easily from within the canopy editor (incl. file browser)